# SQL - LEFT JOIN, but I want COUNT(*) to only count the results from the INNER part of the join

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the number of purchases each customer has made. If they've made 0 purchases, I want to display 0.

**Desired Output:**

```
 -------------------------------------
| customer_name | number_of_purchases |
 -------------------------------------
|    Marg       |          0          |
|    Ben        |          1          |
|    Phil       |          4          |
|    Steve      |          0          |
 -------------------------------------
```

**Customer** Table:

```
 -----------------------------
| customer_id | customer_name |
 -----------------------------
|      1      |      Marg     |
|      2      |      Ben      |
|      3      |      Phil     |
|      4      |      Steve    |
 -----------------------------
```

**Purchases** Table:

```
 --------------------------------------------------
| purchase_id | customer_id | purchase_description |
 --------------------------------------------------
|      1      |       2     |     500 Reams        |
|      2      |       3     |     6 Toners         |
|      3      |       3     |     20 Staplers      |
|      4      |       3     |     2 Copiers        |
|      5      |       3     |     9 Name Plaques   |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

---

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT customer_name, COUNT(*) AS number_of_purchaes 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON customer.customer_id = purchases.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```

However, since it's a `LEFT JOIN`, the query results in rows for customers with no purchases, which makes them part of the `COUNT(*)`. In other words, customers who've made 0 purchases are displayed as having made 1 purchase, like so:

**LEFT JOIN Output:**

```
 -------------------------------------
| customer_name | number_of_purchases |
 -------------------------------------
|    Marg       |          1          |
|    Ben        |          1          |
|    Phil       |          4          |
|    Steve      |          1          |
 -------------------------------------
```

I've also tried an `INNER JOIN`, but that results in customers with 0 purchases not showing at all:

**INNER JOIN Output:**

```
 -------------------------------------
| customer_name | number_of_purchases |
 -------------------------------------
|    Ben        |          1          |
|    Phil       |          4          |
 -------------------------------------
```

How could I achieve my **Desired Output** where customers with 0 purchases are shown?

Comment: `SUM(ISNULL(purchases.customer_id)) AS number_of_purcahses`

Comment: I have added the answer . check it

Comment: added the code and sql fiddle.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `count(*)` use `count(purchase_id)`

```
SELECT customer_name, COUNT(purchase_id) AS number_of_purchaes 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON customer.customer_id = purchases.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer_id,customer_name
```

Comment: include the customer_id in the group by clause to avoid assumption that names are unique.

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this:

**Sample Data:**

```
create table customer(customer_id integer, customer_name varchar(20));

create table purchaser(purchaser_id varchar(20), customer_id integer, description varchar(20));


insert into customer values(1, 'Marg');
insert into customer values(2, 'Ben');
insert into customer values(3, 'Phil');
insert into customer values(4, 'Steve');

insert into purchaser values(1, 2, '500 Reams');
insert into purchaser values(2, 3, '6 toners');
insert into purchaser values(3, 3, '20 Staplers');
insert into purchaser values(4, 3, '20 Staplers');
insert into purchaser values(5, 3, '20 Staplers');

SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, COUNT(p.purchaser_id) AS number_of_purchaes 
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN purchaser p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id 
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ff0a/2

Comment: `customer_name` is not a part of `group by`. won't work

Comment: still it's not right. `customer_name` is in the `select` list but not a part of any `aggregated function` or `group by` clause.

Comment: in MySQL you don't have to group by all columns. You can just group by whatever columns you want.

Comment: It might be not that much strict in `mysql`. `Oracle` and `SQL Server` don't allow this.

Comment: 5.7+ will allow this, even in `set sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, provided customer_id is a PK or unique not null secondary key. When the group by field is unique, other rows from the same table can't be an invalid aggregation as their is only one value possible.

Answer (score 2):

COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL values and duplicates.

COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group, and returns the number of nonnull values.

```
CREATE table customer(customer_id integer , customer_name varchar(20));

create table purchases(purchase_id integer , customer_id integer , purchase_description varchar(30));

INSERT INTO customer ( customer_id, customer_name )
VALUES ( 1, 'Marg' )
     , ( 2, 'Ben' )
     , ( 3, 'Phil' )
     , ( 4, 'Steve' );

INSERT INTO purchases ( purchase_id, customer_id, purchase_description )
VALUES ( 1, 2, '500 Reams' )
     , ( 2, 3, '6 toners' )
     , ( 3, 3, '20 Staplers' )
     , ( 4, 3, '2 Copiers' )
     , ( 5, 3, '9 Name Plaques' );


 SELECT  c.customer_name
      , COUNT(p.purchase_id) AS number_of_purchases
FROM    customer c
        LEFT JOIN purchases p
            ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_name
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(*)` counts rows. You want to count matches, so count from the second table as following:

```
select customer.customer_name , a.number_of_purchases from (
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(purchases.purchase_id) AS number_of_purchaes 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON customer.customer_id = purchases.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer.customer_id) as a 
inner join customer on customer.customer_id=a.customer_id;
```

In other words, the `LEFT JOIN` returns a row when there is no match. That row has a `NULL` value for all the columns in the `purchases` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  customer_name, COUNT(purchase_id) AS number_of_purchases
FROM
  customer AS c
LEFT JOIN purchases AS p ON (c.cid = p.cid)
GROUP BY c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of count(*) use COUNT(purchases.customer_id)

```
SELECT customer_name, COUNT(purchases.customer_id) AS number_of_purchaes 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON customer.customer_id = purchases.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.customer_name,count(p.purchase_id)number_of_purchases FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN 
 Purchases AS p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.customer_name
```